# Change template text

Tags: magento2, template

How can I change below texts ? I would like to change them as "Sign In or Register".

[image]

Comment: In default theme? Did you tried using translation?

Comment: No, this is `aloquick` theme.

Comment: start path hint and get phtml file and change it.

Comment: Thanks @Yogesh. I get code `<div class="customer">
                                    <span class="icon icon-user"><i class="hidden">hidden</i></span>
                                    <div class="top-links">
                                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header.links'); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>`

How can I edit this code ? I  need location of `header.links`.

Comment: You can also go for inline translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want to do is find the XML file that is responsible of setting the `.pthml` file and a `block class` file. It look something like this

```
<block name="header.links" class="Vendor/Namespace/Block/...php" template="Vendor_Namespace::templatefile.phtml />
```

In your case you want to find the one that is called `header.links`. 
You can just do a full search in your theme folder `app/design/vendor/theme` for the word `'header.links'`

`->getChildHtml()` or `->getChildBlock()` means that its going to get the `template file` of a `child block` of that `Block`.

So if you will see something like this

```
<block name="something" class="Vendor/Namespace/Block/...php" template="Vendor_Namespace::templatefile.phtml">
   <block name="header.links" class="Vendor/Namespace/Block/...php" template="Vendor_Namespace::templatefile.phtml" />
</block>
```

In this case `header.links` is a child block of the block `something`.

`Child block` are not shown unless you call them in the `.phtml` file of the parent block.

So now you that you are packed with that information we can start searchin where it defines that text. Search for the child block that is responsible for that line of text. See if its coded within the template file or the class file and adjust those.

If this all does not make any sense to you please look into the next URL:
[Common Layout tasks magento 2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html)

**Solution for you**

Your text is defined within `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

there you see the line :

```
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
```

Copy/paste that file to your relative theme path

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml
```

Now you can adjust it however you want.

Change the text "Create an Account" to "Register"

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Register</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Clear your **var/** folder and if you have it (depends if you are using Magento 2.2.0 or not) **generated/** folder and then you should see this :
[image]

Comment: Thanks @SwAt.Be for your reply. I followed your instruction but did not get `phtml` file. Thanks.

Comment: Well it depends which theme you are using but for the luma theme its within  vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Customer/Layout/default.xml and there you see the 2 template filles account/customer.phtml (located in Magento_Customer/view/frontend/templates/account/customer.phtml) and link/authorization.pthml. You can start searching there

Comment: Within you admin setting you can enable path template hints for storefront within system->configuration->advanced->developer

Comment: Thanks @SwAt.Be. I enabled path template hints for storefront using system->configuration->advanced->developer. In my case path is `/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/link/authorization.phtml`. I got this code there  `<div class="customer"> <span class="icon icon-user"><i class="hidden">hidden</i></span> <div class="top-links"> <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header.links'); ?> </div> </div>`. How can I change those texts ?

Comment: You see the getChildHtml('header.links') which refers to another html part but since its using the magento module customer i think i can help you out here. I will update my post

Comment: Thanks @SwAt.be. Your solution is working. I am fighting with it for 3 weeks. You are the BOSS.